# SQL: how to select distinct values with an offset

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given the following table:

```
id      value     
------- -------
0       1      
1       6      
2       7      
3       9      
4       2      
5       20     
6       21      
7       3
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to select distinct rows where there's a difference between (integer) values of (for example) 3, giving a priority to id (low id value = more prioririty).
Programmatically, I would iterate over values starting from id=0 and discarding rows where value, compared to my current list, has a difference less than 3. Here follows an example in C to give an idea:

```
std::vector<int> filtered_values;
for (int i=0; i<values.size();i++)
{
    bool update = true;
    for (int j=0; j<filtered_values.size();j++)
    {
        if (abs(filtered_values[j]-values[i]) < 3) {
            update = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (update)
        filtered_values.push_back(values[i]);
}
```

Is it possible to do this filtering in SQL?

The result, given the initial table, would be:

```
id      value     
------- -------
0       1      
1       6
3       9      
5       20
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name right. tag added. I'm using SQLite, I though it made no difference

Comment: It makes a huge difference when it comes to analytic/window functions, which are used to look at "rows around the current row"

Comment: So, it looks like you want to return only rows where th value has increased by more than 2 compared to the most recently returned row? Row ID 0, because it's the first, row ID 1 because its `Value` of 6 is 5 more than row ID 0's `Value` of 1, Row 3 because 9 is 3 more than row 1's `Value` (and row 1 was returned, but row 2 was not, so you're comparing row 3 to row 1) and row 5 because 20 is 11 more than row 3's `Value`

Comment: @CaiusJard: correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a [recursive CTE](https://www3.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
with recursive cte as (
  select id, value from tablename
  where id = 0
  union all
  select t.id, t.value
  from cte c inner join tablename t
  on t.id = (select min(id) from tablename where id > c.id and value - c.value >= 3)
)  
select * from cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jvCAxqjizXTtxHmWkhpNRm/0).
Results:

```
| id  | value |
| --- | ----- |
| 0   | 1     |
| 1   | 6     |
| 3   | 9     |
| 5   | 20    |
```